# WillPopScope Widget is Stateful Widget or Stateless Widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to use **WillPopScope** inside Stateless widget its not working.

Comment: It's working has nothing to do with widget type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to look up in Flutter source

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d927c9331005f81157fa39dff7b5dab415ad330b/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/will_pop_scope.dart#L16-L43

> class WillPopScope extends StatefulWidget {

Clearly a stateful Widget.